# addClass working in jsFiddle, but not on my page

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to dynamically add a class to the active tab in the code below, and it works when I run the code in jsFiddle, but not when I run it on my page. I'm not showing any errors in my console, the DOM renders the correct class, but the color is wrong. Can anyone see the error?

[my page is here](http://www.triadbarspecials.com/app)

my code is here:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/app.css" />

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    function getHandler() {
        var days = ['sun', 'mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat'],
            d = new Date(),
            today = d.getDay();
        return days[today];
    }

    $(document).delegate('[data-role="navbar"] a', 'click', function() {
        $(this).addClass('ui-btn-active');
        $('.content_div').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).attr('data-href')).show();
    });

    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('[data-href="' + getHandler() + '"]').trigger('click').addClass('selected');
    });

</script>
<script src="../js/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.js"></script>
<style type="text/javascript">
    .content_div {
        display: none;
    }
    .content_div:first-child {
        display: block;
    }
    .ui-btn-active { color: #eee; }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" data-href="sun">Sun</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-href="mon">Mon</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-href="tue">Tue</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-href="wed">Wed</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-href="thu">Thu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-href="fri">Fri</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-href="sat">Sat</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div><!-- /navbar -->
    <div id="sun" class="content_div">Sunday</div>
    <div id="mon" class="content_div">Monday</div>
    <div id="tue" class="content_div">Tuesday</div>
    <div id="wed" class="content_div">Wednesday</div>
    <div id="thu" class="content_div">Thursday</div>
    <div id="fri" class="content_div">Friday</div>
    <div id="sat" class="content_div">Saturday</div>
</div>
</html>
```

Comment: I'd try looking at that element in Chrome. Using 'Inspect element' you'll be able to all the styles that are applied. app.css may have a style that is being rendered instead of what you expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there's so much CSS overwriting going on here, I decided to do about this a different way. Here's the final code that works for me:

```
$(document).delegate('[data-role="navbar"] a', 'click', function() {
        $('a').removeAttr('style');
        $('.content_div').hide();
        $(this).attr('style', 'color: #eee;');
        $('#' + $(this).attr('data-href')).show();
    });
```

Thanks @DidierGhys for putting me on the right track!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the specificity of your CSS selectors.

You can see it in the console: the styles for the class `.ui-btn-active` are being overriden:

[image]

by your piece of css:

[image]

Try making a more specific selector for the active class, something like `#custom-navbar li .ui-btn-active`

Comment: are you looking at this in firebug? I'm not seeing the same things, but then again I'm still trying to figure out firebug. Anyways I'm sure it's got something to do with the exact way I'm styling the active button.

Comment: No this is Chrome's console, inspecting the anchor tag in the menu